# JDBC connect to host but not in database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am creating an application where you can manage an mySql database, at first i want the user to connect to the host by suppling the hostname, username and password. here is my code:

```
try {
        Class.forName(ServerConnect.JDBC_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Cannot register JDBC Driver...");
    }

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                + toServer.getHostname() + "/hrmanagement?" + "user=" + toServer.getUsername()
                + "&password=" + toServer.getPassword());
        System.out.println("Connected to the server!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out
                .println("Not Connected to the server. Make sure username or password is correct!");
    }
```

my question is, how can i connect without specifying the database so that i can let my user choose which database can he connect to. i tried removing     "/hrmanagement?" but it didn't connect to the server. what can i do?

Comment: As a side note, you should *at least* print the caught `SQLException`'s message in your catch (it can contain useful informations)

Comment: If you remove the "/hrmanagement?", you need to move the question mark to "?user=" ... That's probably the main issue.  I posted a larger answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is, how can i connect without specifying the database so
>   that i can let my user choose which database can he connect to. i
>   tried removing "/hrmanagement?" but it didn't connect to the server.
>   what can i do?

Move the question mark to "?user=".  I think the other answer had this correct.

In terms of changing databases, I believe you can use setCatalog() to use a different database.

From the Connection Page:

> void setCatalog(String catalog)
>            throws SQLException
>
> Sets the given catalog name in order to select a subspace of this
>   Connection object's database in which to work.
>
> If the driver does not support catalogs, it will silently ignore this
>   request.
>
> Calling setCatalog has no effect on previously created or prepared
>   Statement objects. It is implementation defined whether a DBMS prepare
>   operation takes place immediately when the Connection method
>   prepareStatement or prepareCall is invoked. For maximum portability,
>   setCatalog should be called before a Statement is created or prepared.
>
> Parameters:
>       catalog - the name of a catalog (subspace in this Connection object's database) in which to work Throws:
>       SQLException - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed connection See Also:
>       getCatalog()

It would probably be easier to use this version of the call, a little less confusing

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url,
                                       String user,
                                       String password)
                                throws SQLException
```

So your code would look like

```
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + toServer.getHostname(),
           toServer.getUsername(),
           toServer.getPassword());

    conn.setCatalog("someDifferentDB");

    System.out.println("Connected to the server!");

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

As a side note, getConnection will attempt to load the JDBC driver for you, so you don't really need to whole Class.forName try/catch block.  That's a vestige of old code that's not needed for most of the modern JDBC drivers. There's still some around that need it, but I believe mysql conforms to the newer style.  Just make sure the driver is in your classpath on the command line

> java -cp \path\to\mysql\driver\driver.jar myProgram

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html):

> The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:
>
> `jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
>   [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...`

So, remove `hrmanagement`, note that the `/` and `?user...` parts are staying